# Why is my vector files printing fuzzy?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, print-design, vector

I'm printing a document from InDesign that contains vector and raster images. My raster images print great, but my **vector** images are fuzzy around the edges; in some cases the edges are downright jagged.

I've gone back to Illustrator and set the Document Raster Effect Settings to have the Anti-alias checked. I double checked that the resolution was also set to high. I've tried setting my InDesign print graphic settings to All.

Nothing has worked, my vector images (imported to InDesign as .ai files) still print with blurry/jagged edges. Please help!!!

**Edit from original Post:**

I've tested a few new things.

1. Printing the vector images from Illustrator - they turn out great
2. Creating a new document in InDesign and re-importing the .ai files - still print poorly
3. Co-worker printed one of the .ai files from InDesign on his computer - turned out good
4. Exporting the InDesign file as a PDF and printing that - the images turn out great
5. Turning all the vector images to PNGs - the images turn out great

With the last 2 things I tried, I have a work around, but am still puzzled why this is happening. It'd be nice to figure this out for future projects. Could my InDesign program be corrupted?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume your links are not broken?

Comment: to be clear: "imported to indesign" means "Used 'Place' feature and they are linked files"?

Comment: Yes, I used 'Place' and none of my links are broken. As far as InDesign is concerned, I have no errors in the document what-so-ever.

Answer (score 1):

Going with Emilie's comment, are you inserting the images as links? If you don't the vectors will be downsized to a thumbnail, which may cause your issue.

Comment: No, none of my links are broken.